# Can finite sequence of $\pi$ starting from first digit of $\pi$ $3$ be palindromic?

Tags: transcendental-numbers, palindrome

To clarify my question consider the following transcendental number:

$5.123215314159...=5.123215+\pi\cdot10^{-7}$
note that :finite sequence starting from first digit $5$ that is palindromic is $5123215$  .

what about $\pi$?

My reason behind this question is  curiosity, loving number $\pi$ , and contemplating number $\pi$ .

Comment: As far as I am aware this is unknown.  I assume it isn't palindromic in the computable range (because somebody would have pointed that out), but we really don't know much about what happens outside that range.

Comment: As far as we know, the digits of $\pi$ appear to behave like random for all intents and purposes. In this sense, the probability that the first $k$ digits are the beginning of a $2k$-digit or $(2k+1)$-digit palindrome is $2\cdot 10^{-k}$.  Summing such probabilities for all $k> n$ gives $\frac2{9\cdot10^{n}}$, so once we have checked that there is no palindrome up to $n=10000000$, the heuristic probability that there is any palindrome *at all* is unfathomably close to $0$.

Comment: @lulu I do not think that the palindrome property has been checked by someone to , say , the $10^{15}$ th digit but the odds for a palindrome of this length are virtually $0$ considering that the behaviour of the digits of $\pi$ has been shown to be very similat to a pure random digit sequence for awfully many digits. Hagen von Eitzen hit the nail on the head.

Comment: To the author : Do we start after the decimal point ? Then $141$ would be a palindrome , but another is very unlikely.

Comment: @Peter  we start from digit 3 .